# Apply onClick to Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is there any way to "encapsulate" an Iframe with some other element to simulate onClick? I know the Iframe doesn't support events but I need to track clicks from my website that are leaving thru the Iframe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the frame contains page from the same domain (does not violate [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)), you can interact directly with its document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
    oFrame.contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {
        alert("frame contents clicked");
    };
};
</script>
```

If it contains external page then you're out of luck - no way to do what you want for obvious security reasons. Although all the contents is visually parts of the same page, frames coming from different domains must stay separate in terms of scripting. Otherwise any page could e.g. create a hidden iframe loading your webmail and steal your session cookie from it. All the data is accessible to the user, but it should not be accessible to the page author.

Comment: Why is it a security reason? The content is displayed on my page.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper the content will display, but the script can't access the contents if it's on another domain.

Comment: @TheGateKeeper see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) can't explain better than that.

Comment: But wouldn't the content on the Iframe be on my page technically?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper yes, but the browser prevents you from accesing it

Comment: I see, guess I am out of luck then. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @TheGateKeeper Think of web site as a human body and each page is part of the body. Each person and his/her own body, each website and its own pages. Now think of JavaScript as clothing - it covers the body and make it look prettier but **it's private to each person**. You won't go and put your clothes on other person, right? :)

Comment: @Palec thanks, this is indeed a good edit. Just curious, why replace the `'` with `’`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because the correct apostrophe is `’`. At least it is looking the way an apostrophe should look like, unlike the straight `'`, and [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode) Unicode supports its use as such. A similar issue is with hyphen (`-`) versus en-dash (`–`).

Comment: @Palec interesting, but since I don't have it in my keyboard I was under the impression `'` is what we should use.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Most of Unicode is not on one’s keyboard. ☺ But this does not mean we should stick to ASCII. I use XIM with right Ctrl as Compose key under Debian Linux, with very little effort I have all characters I need. Ellipsis (…), dash (–), bullet (•), math symbols (∑, ≤, ≠, , ∞), quotes („czech“, “english”), mod sign (♦), … I like good typography and became really used to it. I’ll stop it now, know I’m OT.

Comment: @Palec well, it is my own post we're "trolling" so all good... if someone consider it noise he'll just flag. Thanks again and good luck! ♫

Answer (score 2):

Try using: https://github.com/vincepare/iframeTracker-jquery

Since it's impossible to read iframe content (DOM) from the parent page due to the same origin policy, tracking is based on the blur event associated to a page/iframe boundary monitoring system telling over which iframe is the mouse cursor at any time.

Match the iframe elements you want to track with a jQuery selector and call iframeTracker with a callback function that will be called when a click on the iframe is detected :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.iframe_wrap iframe').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){
            // Do something when the iframe is clicked (like firing an XHR request)
        }
    });
});
```

And many more options.

Answer (score 1):

The above script will work great for testing the click function in the iframe. More specifically, if you are using Google's newer [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs) tracking code with event tracking to track clicks in the iframe, the above code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
    oFrame.contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'My Frame Was Clicked');
    };
};
</script>
```

and the iframe may look like this (note the id="myframe" is referenced in the javascript):

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.yourowndomain.com" scrolling="yes" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" height="800" style="border:0; overflow:hidden; width:100%;"></iframe>
```

Then to test the event click, if you are familiar with Google's event tracking, in the Google Analytics Dashboard under Standard Reports > Real-Time > Events a click would show up as Event Action: click, Event Label: My Frame Was Clicked.  Or long term in the Dashboard under Behavior > Events.

I've tested this and as the previous poster indicated this will only work when the iframe source is on the same domain.