# Detect an iFrame onClick

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick

I have created an advert banner for homepage which cycles between two adverts. One of the adverts contains an iFrame with a form which was supplied by a company and the url in the iFrame points to the form which is located on their own domain. I want to stop the advert cycling when the user clicks in the iFrame (showing they are using it), because I do not want the advert to change when they are half way through filling out the form. The results get displayed in the same iFrame area too.

I have managed to use jQuery to stop the adverts cycling when the whole advert div area is clicked and this worked fine, but then once I added the iFrame that area of the advert does not respond to the click.

I don't think I can z-index invisible triggers etc on top of the iFrame because this will probably stop visitors being able to use the form inside the iFrame?

Does anybody know how I can get the advert to stop when the iFrame is clicked please?

Currently I am using:

```
$("#The advert DIV").click(function(){
stopLoop();
})
```

Which successful stops the advert cycling, the function called clears an interval looping the adverts. I gave the iFrame an id of advertiFrame and used that as the selector in the above code but the onClick of iFrame did not respond to it.

I'm now stuck on what to do? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply onClick to Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071431/apply-onclick-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be occurred as you are calling an element from inside an iframe.

This may helps you :

```
    <script>
        window.parent.$("#The advert DIV").click(function(){
        stopLoop();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sharry, but it didn't fix my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the limited cross-domain options due to security etc, I eventually used an image placed on top of the iFrame (by z-index) which when clicked fades out and allows access to the iframe. The click on the image triggers the action to stop the image cycle. This works as a solution for me. It would have been great to avoid the user having to click twice to open the first form field in the iFrame but I think this is a satisfactory solution for me on this occasion.