# How to acess the inner directory of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-drive-api

I am trying to embed my google drive folder using iframe

The thing is if i embed the outermost folder using iframe and if i try to navigate within that folder all the content inside it is redirected to google drive

I mean isn't there any way using which i can embed my outermost gdrive folder and can easily navigate through the folders on same page without being redirected to google drive everytime

Here's a [js bin](https://jsbin.com/gehoyizaso/edit?output) for better understanding.
There's a folder , subfolder and a video inside it.
Currently tapping on folder to access the subfolder redirects to google drive
I want every activity happening on the same page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
  .box {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 600px;
        border: 0;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>  
      <iframe class ="box" src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=13kz3MB3h9EwcZTXrLjcOxusHaOPm2nhq#list">
      </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't except if the iframe is from the same domain, This is why payment gateways implement their solutions in iframes. This is [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in action.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), modern browsers won't let you read or modify the content that's inside the iframe.

What you can do, is use [event bubbling](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) to your advantage and override the onclick() of the iframe. [Here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-detect-click-inside-iframe-using-javascript.php) is an example of this.

Comment: I tried it but doesn't seem to work , if you don't mind can please you Post a jsbin or codepen

Comment: What im saying is unless you make so your code runs in the same domain as google drive, you wont be able to detect or override clicks on links inside the iframe. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071431/apply-onclick-to-iframe/44389097