# Get the click position of the mouse on a page with iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page and I want to get the position of the mouse. I do this :

```js
document.onclick = function(click) {
if (click.clientX<340){
    myControl.inputs.selection = false;
    btnRotate.remove();
    btnMove.remove();
    clicked = false;
}
 console.log("Coordonnee point X="+click.clientX+" Y="+click.clientY)
};
```

But I have an Iframe and when I click on it, I don't get the position.
Do you have an idea ? Thank you

Comment: You’d need to keep the iframe from receiving clicks happening above it. Either by placing an element of the parent document _over_ the iframe, or by setting `pointer-events: none` for the iframe (not sure if the latter works.) Of course you will likely not be able to interact with the iframe content any more. Whether that’s something you want, is unclear from your problem description so far.

Comment: Thank you but I need to interact with the iframe, as a result i can't use this solution.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position

Comment: Perhaps you could get the click location inside the iframe, maybe like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071431/apply-onclick-to-iframe/44389097), and then add that to the location of the iframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Track mouse position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790725/javascript-track-mouse-position)

Comment: Thank you to all of you I'll check that

Comment: It doesn't work on iframe though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am using Host listener (mousemove) for getting mouse position in the document with JavaScript as below:

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
console.log(`Mouse X: ${event.clientX}, Mouse Y: ${event.clientY}`);
});

FOR IFRAME:-----

Add id to the Iframe and Get it to add mousemove listener and get coords from event. it will work for you.

let iframeElement = document.getElementById('iframe');

iframeElement.contentDocument.body.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
document.getElementById('coord').innerHTML = `x:${e.clientX} y:${e.clientY}`
});

Code snippet:
[image: HTML/JS Code for absolute mouse position in iframe]

Regards,
Nisha

Comment: I have updated changes for Iframe in the code snippet. It will work for you.

Comment: I have an error, it says :  Property 'contentDocument' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'. Did you mean 'ownerDocument'?

Comment: No, it needs to be contentDocument only. I have attached screenshot of my code snippet. Please refer.